# Show weather data at client's location

Tags: javascript

I am beginner and I want some tips on this code i have written. How can i make it better, shorter cleaner. And the isMobile() Function is borrowed from the internet. It's a Weather App That gets Data from a Weather API and shows it on a Page. You can see a live demo [here](http://talhabalaj.github.io).

```
   // Getting Location of Mobile Client using GPS
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, handleError);
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
// showing the Position and passing to weather API
function showPosition(position) {
    var lat =position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
    dataRec = {
        lat,
        long
    };
    getResultBylatLong(dataRec.lat, dataRec.long);
}
// Handling Error For GPS 
function handleError(error) {
      switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            alert("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
}
// Getting to know about the Client function
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
// Defining the Main Variable
var dataRec = {};
// Getting to know about the Client
if( isMobile.any()) {
    // Getting Coodinates by GPS
    getLocation();
} else {
    // Getting Coodinates, City name, Country name by IP
    locURL = "https://freegeoip.net/json/";
    sampleLocURL = "location.json";
    $.ajax({
           url: locURL,
           dataType: 'json',
           async:false,
           success: function(data) {
            var country = data.country_code;
            var city = data.city;
            var lat = data.latitude;
            var long = data.longitude;
            dataRec = {
                city,
                country,
                lat,
                long
            }; 
        }
    });
    getResultByIP(dataRec.city, dataRec.country, dataRec.lat, dataRec.long);
}
// Getting The Weather on Phone with their GPS
function getResultBylatLong(lat, long) {
    // So Here We are creating a Function That Does the Magic
    _("lat").textContent = lat + " N";
    _("long").textContent = long + " E";
    var apikey = "8691065341cc4bc2b2030259170801";
    var url = "https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key="+ apikey + "&q=" + lat +"," + long;
    getJSON(url);
}
// Getting The Weather on PC with their IP
function getResultByIP(city, country, lat, long) {
    // So Here We are creating a Function That Does the Magic
    _("lat").textContent = lat + " N";
    _("long").textContent = long + " E";
    var apikey = "8691065341cc4bc2b2030259170801";
    var url = "https://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key="+ apikey + "&q=" + city +"," + country;
    getJSON(url);
}
// Helper Function
function _(rl) {
    return document.getElementById(rl);
}
// Main JSON
function getJSON(url) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON(url, function( data ) {
            loc = data.location.name;
            cont = data.location.country;
            lat = data.location.lat;
            lon = data.location.lon;
            cond = data.current.condition.text;
            icon = data.current.condition.icon;
            if(icon.startsWith("//cdn.apixu.com/weather/64x64/night/")){
                icon = icon.substr(36, 7);  
            } else {
                icon = icon.substr(34, 7);  
            }
            temp = Number(Math.round(data.current.temp_c));
            _("weatherImage").src = "icons/" + icon;
            _("weatherTemp").textContent = temp + "°C";
            _("weatherCondition").textContent = cond;
            _("weatherLocation").textContent = loc + ", " + cont;
            _("lat").textContent = lat + " N";
            _("long").textContent = lon + " E";
            document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = "Today's Weather in " + loc;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: For the future, the title of a code review question should be the one-line summary of the code. For more details see [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few points:

- getResultByIP() call should be inside the success function. currently is outside which causing your app to fail on desktop browsers.
- sampleLocURL variable is not in use.
- It would be nice if you had mobileApiService & broserApiService that both
  implement the getLocation() method. all relevant logic (for mobile and for browser) will be held there.